# Slick 3.0.0 documentation Error

Tags: slick

I'm following the Slick documentation that can be found at the following location:

http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html

In that I'm looking into the "Populating the Database" section. I'm not able to find the schema method defined for the TableQuery, hence I'm not able to populate my H2 database with initial values!

Is there something wrong with the documentation? It is confusing the hell out of me! Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
  val h2DbConfig = Map(
    "default.driver" -> "slick.driver.H2Driver$",
    "default.db.driver" -> "org.h2.Driver",
    "default.db.url" -> "jdbc:h2:yourDbName;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
  )

 ConfigFactory.parseMap(h2DbConfig) // gives you a typesafe config
```

Once you have the typesafe config object containing the h2 database, you create the tables as below:

```
  private def h2SchemaSetUp = {

    val schema = slick.dbio.DBIO.seq(
      (Table1.tbl1.schema ++
        Table2.tbl2.schema
      ).create
    )
    Await.result(db.run(schema), 5.seconds)
  }
```

You then insert values into the created Schema as per Slick's documentation!